# Question for finding bound for $f'(z)$[CSIR-December 2011]

Tags: complex-analysis

> [image]

---

My attempt:-
(1)Taking $f(z)=.5$, So, $g(z)= \begin{cases} 
      \frac{.5}{z} & z\neq 0 \\
     0 & z=0
   \end{cases}
$

So, I can eliminate (1) and (2)

I am trying to apply [Schwarz pick lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Schwarz-PickLemma.html) for (c), But I am not able to make $|f'(z)|\leq \frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}\leq 1$

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(3) is false by taking $f(z)=z^2.$

(4) follows from Cauchy's integral theorem: $$f'(0)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z)}{z^2} dz,$$ where $C$ is a circle of radius $r < 1$.  Bound $f'(0)$ using the bound for $f$.  Then take $r \to 1^-.$

Comment: $$|f'(0)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z)}{z^2} dz|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi } \int_C |\frac{f(z)}{z^2}| |dz|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_C \frac{1}{|z|^2} |dz|$$

Comment: How it is less than $1$?

Comment: @Unknownx $|z|=1$ on $C$, and the circumference of $C$ is $2 \pi$.  Also, you should replace $|dz|$ with $dz$; you don't have to take absolute values of the differential...I suppose that makes sense, but it's already "positive" in a way...

Comment: Since function is only defined on $D$. How would take counter integral over a curve which is outside the definition?

Comment: Take it on a circle of radius $R<1$ and let $R\rightarrow1$.

Comment: @Unknownx Yes, good point!  But you can take any circle of radius $r < 1$ and then let $r \to 1^-.$

Comment: @ThomasShelby Thanks.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(z)=z^2$ for which $|f'(3/4)|=3/2\ge 1$. So (c) is false.

Option (d) is true by using Schwarz Pick theorem,

$|f'(0)|\leq \frac{1-|f(0)|^2}{1-|0|^2}=1-|f(0)|^2\leq 1$

Comment: what is the guarentee that $f(0)\leq 1$?

Comment: Given in question that $|f(z)|\le 1\implies |f(0)|\le 1$  so ...

Comment: okay Thank you very much.

Comment: #Unknown x....My pleasure

Comment: I have one more doubt, what if $f(0)=0$?.

Comment: In that case $g$ must be holomorphic.

Comment: will $|g(z)|\leq 1$?

Comment: consider a circle of radius $r<1$. Then maximum modulus principle, and limit $r \to 1$ $|f(z)|/|z|\leq 1$

Comment: What about $|f'(0)|$?

Comment: Please ask a separate question for further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(z)=f(0)+zf'(0)+\frac{z^2}{2!}f''(0)+ . . .$$

$(1)\qquad$ Since $f(z)$ is analytic / holomorphic, so from the above equation we have $$f(0)=0, \qquad g(z)= \frac{f(z)}{z}=f'(0)+\frac{z}{2!}f''(0)+ . . .$$
Therefore $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $D$. $\qquad$**(Option $1$ is true)**

$(2)\qquad$  $$|g(z)|=|\frac{f(z)}{z}|\le 1 \qquad \forall z \in D$$(given that $|f(z)|\le 1$ and $|z|\lt 1$).$\qquad$**(Option $2$ is true)**

$(3)\qquad$ By Schwarz Pick Lemma, $$|f'(z)|\le \frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}$$

Given $$|f(z)|\le 1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad |z|\lt 1$$

So $|f'(z)|$ may or may not be less than or equal to $1\quad \forall z\in D.$$\qquad$**(Option $3$ is not  true)**

$(4)\qquad$ $$|g(0)|=|f'(0)|\le 1$$ $\qquad$**(Option $4$ is true)**